# Is there a JFK airport hotel which allows cats?

Tags: hotels, stopovers, pets, jfk

There are a number of hotels in a group (Hampton, etc) by JFK airport.

Is there one which allows pet cats (cat travelling in a cat box) to stay overnight with human guests?  (Whether in the room or separate, doesn't matter.)

(The poor cat will have had a hell of a long flight and needs a decent rest.)

I could not find this information collated anywhere, oddly: You'd think there'd be a "pet friendly" tickbox on Expedia, TA, etc -- perhaps I've missed something?

Comment: Look for a La Quinta. They are pet friendly everywhere, with no added fee.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Several hotels in the area listed on Trip Advisor as "pet friendly" but only accept dogs.  Blatant discrimination!  La Quinta JFK accepts cats and there is no surcharge.

Comment: Do you have any references, from the hotel website for example, to back this up?

Comment: Just FTR I can confirm a reservation at La Quinta, cat OK, no surcharge.

Comment: congrats on your bounty!

Answer (score 6):

Yes there are a number that allow small pets in the JFK area. Try Travelocity which has a 'Pets allowed (conditions apply)' check box.

Be sure to check the conditions- in my experience some hotels levy exorbitant 'cleaning fees' when a pet stays- for that price the pet could have dysentery and be doing somersaults and they'd still come out ahead.